# drawImage raises script65535 on IE11

Tags: javascript

I'm making a chess game, and I use 2 layers of canvas to draw the board and the pieces.
The general code to draw pieces looks like this:

```
drawPiece = function(ctx,x,y,type,color) {

  var url = getPieceImg(type,color);
  var image = new Image;

  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image,x,y,40,40);
  };

  image.src = url;
};
```

There is a random glitch that makes the line `ctx.drawImage(image,x,y,40,40);` crash.
IE's console shows me this: (line 805 is the aforementioned line)

```
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to a method or property
File : chess-canvas.html, line : 805, column : 9
```

I tested for the nature and form of the inputs to `drawImage`, including ctx, but they are always correct. Moreover, I can do twice the same move with varying results. The odds are about 1/15 to glitch out.

...I realized that bringing out 'inspect element' raises the odds of the glitch happening to roughly 1/6.
...I tried debugging with a breakpoint, and the bug *never* happened. As if waiting for input allowed enough time to... something!!

I could not reproduce the glitch on browsers other than my IE (11, 64bit, windows 7).

This seems like a very specific browser issue, I'm not sure if it belongs on StackOverflow. I'm sorry if that is the case... this glitch is so bizarre, though!

The entire code is also found on codecademy, where the issue is also observable; http://www.codecademy.com/TamaYoshi/codebits/5Tm2R1/edit

Any clue what's going on?

**EDIT for a WORKAROUND:** Weird issues make weird workarounds. I'm laughing right now;

```
image.onload = function() {
  try {
    ctx.drawImage(image,x,y,40,40);
  }
  catch (err)
  {
    setTimeout(function() {drawPiece(ctx,x,y,type,color)}, 1);
  }
};
```

AND IT WORKS. But why?!

Comment: You are sure image url must be type and color, and what is getPieceImg()?

Comment: `getPieceImg()` returns the url of the image of the piece of the correct type and color (not a built-in function). Pieces display fine, so that's not the issue.

Comment: `Pieces display fine, so that's not the issue.` That sounds like an unfounded assumption to me.

Comment: I just found a workaround that shows how weird the issue really is; I cannot *comprehend* how `getPieceImg()` could not work; all it does is literally just return a URL. And it works all the time; the issue here is really with drawImage. I even debugged 'url' and it has the right value, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue with Kineticjs and I have also used setTimeout function with timeout value 0. It works in IE9, IE10 and IE11. As like you, I don't know why it works.

```
setTimeout(drawingFunction, 0);
```

Still investigating to find the root cause. If I manage to find the root cause, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

My OS teacher has given me some insight on the issue.
This may or may not explain the problem entirely, but it seems to explain it to some degree.

**Timeouts** cause the OS to switch to kernel mode, or more precisely, to allow the next available thread to load. This is equally true for a timeout of `time=0`; the only difference here being that the OS will pick the thread as soon as it comes across it.

The subtlety lies in the fact that if *for some reason* that image is not fully loaded due to a scheduling error, asking to '`fetch back`' the missing data by switching threads is sufficient to fix the scheduling error.